# Iterate a String map and set in Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hashmap

I have a Map of Strings like `(["id":"1"]["name":"text"]["category":"mobile"]......)` and I have a class to set all the key and values

```
class Test{
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String category;
   public void setId(String id){
   }
   public void setName(String id){
   }
   public void setCategory(String id){
   }
}
```

The String map is having around 100 of keys like the above so is there a way to get from the map and set in the object through a iteration or I need to do it manually for all the keys?

Comment: Please clarify your `<Key,Value>` types and how they correspond to the near empty `Test` class.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the `Map` directly. For example: where ever you want to use `id`  use `map.get("id")` instead.